# how to move object in the direction it is bring hit in(as3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a ball and a player.What should I do to move ball in the direction in which the player hits it?I tried comparing x and y of player and ball. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post some code what have you tried so far...

I think with some if conditions you can decide which should be the ball movement direction. I will give you a hint:

```
if(player.hitTestObject(ball)) {
//if player hit the ball
//now you should see the possition of ball and of the player

//[we need some variables, you will see for what later on]
var x_direction, y_direction;

if(player.x < ball.x) { 
    //that means your ball is in the right , and player in the left 
    //and the ball should change position x with '+' sign --> (you will use this a bit latter when you will move the ball)
    //now we will use the x_direction variable to retain the direction in which the ball should move
    //because player is in the left (player.x < bal.x) that means the ball should move to right

    x_direction = 'right';
} 

else {
    //it's opposite ....
    //because player is in the right (player.x > bal.x) that means the ball should move to left

    x_direction = 'left';
}

//now we finished with x...we should check also the y axis

if(player.y < ball.y) { 
    //that means your ball is below the player 
    //player hit the ball from the top

    y_direction = 'down';
} 

else {
    //it's opposite ....
    //the ball should go up
    y_direction = 'up';
}


// now we have to move the ball
// we do this according to possition we checked before

if(x_direction == 'right') {
    //you should define your speed somewhere up like var speed = 10;

    ball.x = ball.x + speed; // remember the sign '+'?
    //or ball.x += speed;
} else {
    ball.x -= speed;
}

//and the same with y direction
if(y_direction == 'down') {
    //you should define your speed somewhere up like var speed = 10;

    ball.y += speed;
} else {
    ball.y -= speed;
}

// you can put this movement in an enterframe loop and make the movement....
```

}

*Hope this will help you to make it working...*